# About Android R.java File

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a new android app project but google updated adt's and in revision 20 new screen corresponds. When i create a new project R.java file is not generated, i tried millions time but result is same. I did not change any line of code, it does not come by default. Help me guys. Thanks.

Comment: is it showing an any error in console

Comment: Please provide some information about your setup.

Comment: Usually it means that there are some problems in your resources files (layouts). After you correct these errors R class should be generated

Comment: can you post your logcat, so we can solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

do this steps :

```
1. Clean your project.
2. If their is import android.R statement, remove this.
3. close your project & start it again & rebuild it.
4. check out your xml file.
```

Hope this ll help.

Answer (score 1):

Check for any errors in your xml files and res folder.
Then go to Project>Clean and clean ur project.

Then ur R.java will be generated

Comment: except if he has unclicked "Build Automatically". Then he needs to click that again.

Comment: I tried these steps.But there is no change. I saw these site : http://www.muharremtac.com/metin/yeni_adt_ile_android_sifirdan_uygulama_olusturma_ekranlari_degisti-705, i updated eclipse and then i can not create a successful project. I do not change any line, it creates default but when a new project created it comes with errors - 'R can not be resolved to a variable'

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure all your xml files are error free
2. Clean
3. Build `// don't forget this one`

Comment: I tried but it's same. I made a mistake while setting it up i guess. I will try to set up again. Thanks for your helps guys.